# QToolButton don't hide popup menu after triggering action

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a `QToolButton` with a popup menu on a toolbar. Popup menu has a number of checkable actions, and it looks like this:

[image]

Problem is - popup menu closes every time I check/uncheck the action, but I want it to stay opened so I can check a number of actions with no need to reopen popup menu. How can I achieve this?

Edited:

Found this workaround - [Prevent a QMenu from closing when one of its QAction is triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050462/prevent-a-qmenu-from-closing-when-one-of-its-qaction-is-triggered)

It looks a bit different but still ok for me:

[image]

Comment: You need to install an event filter and do custom handling. I think you need to do something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813494/qcombobox-with-checkboxes

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I've tried eventFilter but I couldn't find valid event type. And I also can't find `view()` or `viewport()` in `QToolButton`

Comment: I don't see your attempts or any code sample. And I don't understand, why you are looking `view`or `viewport` in `QToolButton`?

Comment: May I suggest that you post your solution as an answer and accept it for yourself? It will make easier to everybody to find it.

Comment: Won't it be considered as a duplicate?

Comment: Hello, how did you solve this? It would be nice if you answered your own question with the code you ended up using, and accepted it.