# How to create a Multi-item selection dropdown list?

Tags: python, user-interface, enaml

I want to create a multi-item selection drop-down in enaml.

ComboBox widget offers this but we can only select one item at a time.
Same is the case with ObjectCombo widget (however slightly different in functionality from ComboBox).

Even something which closely replicates the end-functionality of being able to select multi items from a list, will be helpful, even if it's not a drop-down necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PopupMenu](http://enaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/ex_popup_menu.html) and make the actions checkable.

[image: enaml multi select menu]

Like this:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2018, Nucleic Development Team.
#
# Distributed under the terms of the Modified BSD License.
#
# The full license is in the file COPYING.txt, distributed with this software.
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
""" This example demonstrates how to popup a menu.

A menu can be popped up in 2-ways. The first is by declaring the menu as
a child of a widget and setting the 'context_menu' attribute to True. The
second method is by creating the menu on-demand, and then invoking it's
'popup()' method to show the menu at the current mouse location.


"""
from __future__ import print_function
from enaml.widgets.api import (
    Window, Container, PushButton, Menu, Action, Field
)
from enaml.core.api import Looper

enamldef PopupMenu(Menu): menu:
    attr selected = set()
    attr choices = []
    Looper:
        iterable << choices
        Action:
            text = loop_item
            triggered :: print(text + ' triggered')
            checkable = True
            checked << self.text in selected
            checked ::  selected.add(self.text) if self.checked else selected.remove(self.text)


enamldef Main(Window):
    Container:
        PushButton:
            text = 'Popup Menu'
            attr selected = set()
            clicked :: PopupMenu(selected=self.selected,
                                 choices=['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bam']).popup()
        Field:
            text = 'Context Menu'
            read_only = True
            PopupMenu:
                context_menu = True
                choices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: yes, this will work for the question, however when making many selections, the popup has to be clicked several times, there is no way to keep it in the active state?

Comment: You can re-show the menu in the action triggered handler with `triggered :: menu.proxy.widget.show()` but it flickers between clicks as its showing/hiding. If that doesn't suite you, you probably need to implement a custom menu or modify the one here https://github.com/nucleic/enaml/blob/master/enaml/qt/qt_menu.py. You can also try to post a question here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/enaml

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050462/prevent-a-qmenu-from-closing-when-one-of-its-qaction-is-triggered/11571550#11571550 if you want to make a custom widget